# Why isn't "sprite" defined inside this function?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, undefined, typeerror

Fiddle in question: http://jsfiddle.net/dqDAv/2/

In line 146 I pass the object `"Player"` in as a parameter of `sprite` in the method `render()`

Object

```
var player = new Sprite({
    'left': spriteLeftAnim,
    'right': spriteRightAnim
}, 'right', canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 44, 108, 100);
```

Method

```
function Render() {
ctx.clearRect(0,0, 500, 500);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,400);
ctx.lineTo(500,400);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke(); 
drawSprite(player); // <- Parameter
}
```

So, why isn't `sprite` defined in:

```
function drawSprite(sprite) {
ctx.drawImage(
    sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].tileset.image, 
    sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].frames[sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].currentFrame].split(',')[0] * sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].tileset.tileWidth,
    sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].frames[sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].currentFrame].split(',')[1] * sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].tileset.tileHeight,
    sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].tileset.tileWidth,
    sprite.stateAnimations[sprite.currentState].tileset.tileHeight,
    Math.round(sprite.x),
    Math.round(sprite.y),
    sprite.width,
    sprite.height
);
}
```

Comment: Don't post duplicates like this. You can edit your previous question to add in the extra details.

Comment: That is a completely different fiddle, however. I'm talking about an error here, which is caused because the sprite isn't defined (So I tried to discern what the other fiddle did differently than I did, but didn't come to an answer). I tried using the other fiddle to get an answer on how sprite was defined, so I could work the answer out myself, but since "sprite" itself isn't the problem it seems, I'm at a loss and trying with my code in question. I'm only posting this because my previous question and the javascript chatbox couldn't help.

Comment: Sorry if it seems like a duplicate, this wasn't my intention.

Comment: The initial error is because you start your animation with a call to `Loop()` _before_ you create the `player` object. Move `Loop()` to the end: http://jsfiddle.net/dqDAv/3/

Comment: Thanks! Now to get rid of the 100 other errors hehe.

Comment: Well the next one is in your `Update()` function you refer to a variable `sprite` which is not defined - you probably meant to use `player`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you call "Loop()" before you initialize "player".

Things like this are extremely easy to unravel with something like the Chrome debugger, or even `console.log()` calls.  You just have to work backwards from the point in your code at which you find out that things are not what you expect. In this case, that would be the point at which you call "drawSprite()".  If "sprite" is undefined, then that must mean that whatever was passed in was undefined — the variable "player". So put a breakpoint where "player" is initialized and another before the call to "drawSprite()". And so on.